# benefit sb. in doing sth

Tags: word-usage

I am aware that "benefit" as a verb means

> to be helped by something or to help someone

for instance, this

> They argued that the tax will mainly **benefit** the rich.

means that tax is good for rich people.

Consider this

> Computer-aided diagnosis (CAD) systems **benefit** physicians **in** reducing workload and improving diagnostic accuracy for medical examination.

which uses the pattern `benefit sb. in doing sth.`

Is it idiomatic to use "benefit" that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is quite idiomatic, and is used all the time.  It means that it is beneficial for a particular purpose, or when in a particular context.

Comment: Thank you. Does "beneficial **for** a particular purpose" mean something like "beneficial **to** the health" where "health" is the "purpose"

Comment: Well, "to" in that case means specifically that "health" is what receives the benefit (and you'd usually say something like "beneficial to **your** health"), so "health" is not a purpose there.  By "for a particular purpose" I meant that in your example, "benefit physicians in reducing workload" means that the physicians receive the benefit, but the purpose of the benefit or the way in which they are benefitted is "reducing workload".

Comment: I guess I've got it clearly. Thank you, that's very kind of you.